# Expression.Error: Parquet.Document is only supported on 64-bit systems

Tags: visual-studio, powerquery, parquet, azure-analysis-services

Helo eveyone! I need to load a parquet file into Analysis Services (Visual Studio), so I connect my SSAS through the Azure Blob Storage Connection and I can see the directory with my files normally. The problem start here, when I try read my parquet files I receive the error: "Expression.Error: Parquet.Document is only supported on 64-bit systems."

My M code it's:

let
Source = AzureStorage.Blobs("https://<blob_name>.blob.core.windows.net/"),
#"https://<blob_name> blob core windows net/// parquet" = Source{[#"Folder Path"="https://<blob_name>.blob.core.windows.net/",Name="/.parquet"]}[Content],
#"Imported Parquet" = Parquet.Document(#"https://<blob_name> blob core windows net/// parquet")
in
#"Imported Parquet"

I try change the plataform from Visual Studio to x64

Comment: One possible solution is to use the Power Query Editor in Excel to load the Parquet file and then import the data into Analysis Services.